# Disable query cache for specific user/schema?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to disable the query cache just for a specific database / user / schema?

I have both production and staging environment on the same Mysql server (2 distinct databases) where my PHP app connects and obviously I don't want to disable the cache on my production DB.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why disable it in your staging db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not per user, but you can do it per connection.  From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html):

> Individual clients can control cache behavior for their own connection
>   by setting the SESSION query_cache_type value. For example, a client
>   can disable use of the query cache for its own queries like this:
>
> mysql> SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF;

Comment: yep, I saw that. My problem is that I don't control the PHP app and would need to do that on all php queries when opening the db connection :)  I was trying to simplify my problem

Comment: @AlfaTeK - Hmm.. best I can think of then might be to use MySQL Proxy with some Lua scripts to inject that statement into each connection?